Apparent elastic modulus formula and meaning of squared Poisson's ratio
I come from a maths background but I am currently engaged in a project which involves viscoelasticity modelling, so stress and strain come up a lot. In some papers I've read (here and here) people mention the "apparent elastic modulus" $K$, and give its formula as: $$\begin{equation} K=\frac{E}{1-\nu^2} \text{,} \end{equation}$$ where $E$ is Young's modulus and $\nu$ is Poisson's ratio.
The trouble here is that when I try to look up this formula or the apparent elastic modulus in general, I can't seem to find anything related to this topic. Even more confusingly, different names and notations are used for different things. For example, Wikipedia lists $K$ as the Bulk modulus, which has a different physical meaning and wouldn't suit my context, but regardless, the formulae listed at the bottom of the page show nothing similar to what I am looking for.
This paper mentions a formula for "dimensionless torsional rigidity": $\alpha=2\rho(1-\nu^2/\beta)$, where $\beta=E_y/E_x$ and $\rho=G/E_x$, $E_x$ and $E_y$ being Young's moduli in the x and y direction and $G$ being the shear modulus. Even though this is again a different physical context (torsion as opposed to mine being unilateral traction), this is the formula most "resembling" my own and the only one I have found so far that mentions $\nu^2$.
On that note, is there any physical meaning to $\nu^2$, or $1-\nu^2$ for that matter? If its purpose is only to make the Poisson's ratio argument positive, $1-\nu$ is already positive, as the theoretical range of $\nu$ is from $-1$ to $0.5$, correct?
In summary, is anyone familiar with calculating the apparent elastic modulus from Young's modulus and Poisson's ratio? Could someone recommend reading material on the matter?

It seems that the answer is related to Hertz models in contact mechanics, which all papers mentioning this formula have as they are using atomic or scanning force microscopy (AFM/SFM). My question still stands though: do the apparent elastic modulus have any physical meaning or is it just a shorthand in this case?

1-nu^2 pops up in various equations related to bending in plates with isotropic materials. Yes it has a physical meaning, in that those equations can be derived from a set of assumptions, and the results correlate with real tests. I'd guess that Timoshenko's books would cover this.

Rather than viscoelasticity, the application to retina, which can be modelled as a thin shell structure may be important. In such structures, normal stress ($\sigma_z$) can often be neglected in comparison to in-plane stresses ($\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$), so Hooke's law simplifies (biaxial stress):
$$\epsilon_x = \frac{1}{E}\cdot\left(\sigma_x-\nu\cdot \sigma_y\right)$$
$$\epsilon_y = \frac{1}{E}\cdot\left(\sigma_y-\nu\cdot\sigma_x\right)$$
Deriving $\sigma_x$ from the first one:
$$\sigma_x = \nu\cdot \sigma_y+E\cdot \epsilon_x$$
and substituting this to the second one:
$$\epsilon_y = \frac{1}{E}\cdot\left(\sigma_y-\nu\cdot\left(\nu\cdot \sigma_y+E\cdot \epsilon_x\right)\right) = \sigma_y\cdot\frac{1-\nu^2}{E}-\nu\cdot\epsilon_x$$
Finally, you can express equation for $\sigma_y$:
$$\sigma_y = \frac{E}{1-\nu^2}\cdot\left(\epsilon_y+\nu\cdot\epsilon_x\right)$$
Analogically, you can get:
$$\sigma_x = \frac{E}{1-\nu^2}\cdot\left(\epsilon_x+\nu\cdot\epsilon_y\right)$$
Now in case where lateral deformation is restrained:
$$\sigma_x\left(\epsilon_y=0\right) = \frac{E}{1-\nu^2}\cdot\epsilon_x = K\cdot \epsilon_x$$
and similarly:
$$\sigma_y\left(\epsilon_x=0\right) = \frac{E}{1-\nu^2}\cdot\epsilon_y = K\cdot \epsilon_y$$

Thank you for your reply, this was helpful. Could you recommend some reading on this area if you're familiar with any?

@Воин This presentation from Seoul university helped me with understanding of some issues related to plate bending and you can also see my answer in a different form on slide 18 there. Other than that, try looking for shell or plate elasticity, any book about strength of materials which also covers shells or beams might be helpful.
